# Chart.js scatter axis titles

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to add x and y axis titles on my scatter chart, something like this:
[image](https://images.ctfassets.net/itcc7vu35nc1/3sLByWrVcGdAE6cx2hfz2B/6834f2ac7bab6a6768cb9f483424bfdf/scatter-plot_usage-guidelines_shapes-do_2x.png)

I read the documentation on chartJS but everything I tried didn't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
  let healthy = healRBP.map((v, i) => ({ x: v, y: healChol[i] }))
  let cardio = cardioRBP.map((v, i) => ({ x: v, y: cardioChol[i] }))

// Get variables passed from Flask.
  let patientX = [{{ rbp }}]
  let patientY = [{{ chol }}]

  let patient = patientX.map((v, i) => ({ x: v, y: patientY[i] }))
  var ctx2 = document.getElementById("scatterChart").getContext("2d");
  var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx2, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Healthy',
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(0, 255, 0, 0.3)",
        borderColor: "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
        data: healthy,
      }, {
        label: 'Cardio',
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.3)",
        borderColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
        data: cardio,
      }, {
        label: 'Patient',
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
        borderColor: "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
        data: patient,
        pointRadius: 10,
        pointHoverRadius: 12
      }],
      options: {},
    }
  });
```

What my graph looks like now:
[image: my graph]

Answer (score 0):

You can put labels on your axes by configuring the scales part of the options object like this:
scales:{
y:{
scaleLabel:{
display:true,
labelString: "test"
}
}
},

If you are using V2 you will have to put the object in an array called yAxes for y and xAxes for x.

V3 docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/labelling

V2 docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html